# Do I need a model to insert through IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a model for `Product` and associated tables `products` & `departments` in the database.

I don't have a model for `Department`.

In `IRB`, I can do this successfully:

```
p = Product.new
```

But when I do this:

```
d = Department.new
```

It throws,

> NameError: uninitialized constant Department

Is that happening because the `Rails` model for `Department` isn't there?

If you already have the table, how do you create the model (do I have to generate and run `rake db:migrate`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes error is due to not having a Department class or model. You can just create a department.rb and inherited from active record in your app/models directory with your favourite editor. for example with vim you can do

```
vim app/models/department.rb
```

edit the above file to have following

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and then reload the irb session with reload!

Answer (score 2):

Rails follow `Convention over Configuration` also the ActiveRecord follows the ORM (Object Relational Mapping)  and according to it :

All the `models` in the Rails application has a `Singular` class name with a `plural` name in the `database` . For ex : In your case ,

`Department` model will refer to `departments` table in the database , where you have the `departments` table but not a `model` Department in your Rails application .

> By default, Active Record uses some naming conventions to find out how
>   the mapping between models and database tables should be created.
>   Rails will pluralize your class names to find the respective database
>   table. So, for a class Book, you should have a database table called
>   books. The Rails pluralization mechanisms are very powerful, being
>   capable to pluralize (and singularize) both regular and irregular
>   words.

Now , when you try to initialize the `Department` model in `irb` like

```
$ > d=Department.new
```

What this will do is will search a class name as `Department` in your `app/models` directory , if it finds this class it will relate it to the similar `departments` table in the database and will initialize this `object`.

It will obviously throw an `error` as you haven't declared any Class as `Department` in your `app/models/Department.rb` .

So , what you need to do now is to declare a class name as `Department` in your models directory according to the `@shani`'s answer :

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```